# Proper syntax for DB::select()->from('ads')->where using multiple search values

Tags: mysql, sql

Can't figure out the correct syntax to return database results based on multiple values

This is my code, but I need to count how many ads have id_category 351, 353, 354, 355, 358, 360, 361, 361 and 363.

```
    if ($cat->id_category_parent==='350') {
$queryA = DB::select()->from('ads')->where('id_category', '=' , '351, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363');
$resultA = $queryA->execute();
}
```

I also tried like this:

```
    if ($cat->id_category_parent==='350') {
$queryA = DB::select()->from('ads')->where('id_category', '=' , '351' || 'id_category', '=' , '353');
$resultA = $queryA->execute();
}
```

and like this:

```
DB::select()->from('ads')
->where('id_category', '=' , '351')
->where('id_category', '=' , '353')
->where('id_category', '=' , '354');
etc...
```

I even tried the statement orWhere but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [IN statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

```
if ($cat->id_category_parent==='350') {
   $queryA = DB::select()->from('ads')->where('id_category', 'IN', [351, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363]);
   $resultA = $queryA->execute();
}
```

the `IN` statement is used to check if a value is in an array, as is the case for you

EDIT:
i changed the code so it uses an array instead of a string

Comment: It's throwing an error message: 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''(351, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363)'' at line 1 [ SELECT * FROM `yc3_ads` WHERE `id_category` IN '(351, 353, 354, 355, 357, 358, 360, 361, 362, 363)' ]

Comment: what framework are you using? because it also adds the ' making it a string instead of an array

Comment: kohana framework. I tried without the ' but same error message though...

Comment: @FusionDesign i changed my answer, it now uses an array as input instead of a string